# Create a Single CSV from Muliple JSON Files

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

Looking for a way to modify the script, below to produce a single CSV from multiple JSON files.  It should include multiple rows, each row returning values for the same fields, but tied to a single JSON (ROW 1 = JSON 1, ROW 2 = JSON 2, etc.).  The following produces a CSV with one row of data.

```
   import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_json("pywu.cache.json")
    df = df.loc[["station_id", "observation_time", "weather", "temperature_string", "display_location"],"current_observation"].T
    df = df.append(pd.Series([df["display_location"]["latitude"], df["display_location"]["longitude"]], index=["latitude", "longitude"]))
    df = df.drop("display_location")
    print(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])
    df = pd.to_numeric(df, errors="ignore")
    pd.DataFrame(df).T.to_csv("CurrentObs.csv", index=False, header=False, sep=",")
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the write mode? It [defaults](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to `'w'`, but perhaps `'a'` will meet your needs.

Comment: I have not, but will give it a shot!

Comment: if you have a lot of writing to do (e.g. tens of files, each pretty small), it'll be better for your resources to combine the data frames first, and then write only once. If your data frames are massive, it may be better to append after each to avoid memory issues.